# Expressing a regretful wish

Tags: grammar, english-to-japanese, modality

What is a good way to express a wish about something that won't or is unlikely to happen?

For example:

> I wish I were tall enough to be allowed on that roller coaster.
>
> I wish I could eat that much and not gain weight.
>
> I wish I had been born 100 years ago instead.

etc.

Answer (score 5):

A good way to do this is to use the construct Conditional + いいのに.

For example:

> トラだったらいいのに
>   I wish I were a tiger
>
> もっと背が高ければよかったのに
>   I wish I were taller
>
> その車を買うのに十分なお金があったらいいのに
>   I wish I had enough money to buy that car
>
> きれいだったらいいのに
>   I wish she looked pretty

It's a pretty simple construct, and any conditional form can work.

Comment: More naturally, よかったのに ＞ いいのに、あったら ＞ あれば, etc.  Interestingly enough, however, you correctly used だったら.

Comment: Just curious, why are those more natural than what I had before?

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thankyou :)

Comment: Can you also use なら and ば for this? Is there any difference in meaning?

Comment: @Blavius いいのに is much more like "why (on earth) don't?" than counterfactual. I mean, it can be, but doesn't especially sound like. We use ればなあ/たらなあ more often if you want a non-past tense.

Comment: I think your examples in English are 2nd Conditional, but the Japanese translation are 3rd conditional, aren't they?

Comment: In Genki we learn this grammar point as 〜ばよかった.  What does the のに add?