# how to use: ~ばいいのに

Tags: grammar, expressions

what does it mean when a sentence ends with ~ばいいのに?

Example sentence:
そんなに聞いてほしいなら言えばいいのに

and what does のに mean at the end of sentences?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42408/9831

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> そんなに聞いてほしいなら**言えばいいのに**。

It can mean "If you want to be heard (or, want your story heard, want me to listen to you) so much, **you should just say so. / why don't you just say so?**"

～～ばいいのに can mean "You should do~~ (but you haven't done so)" or "You should have done~~ (but you didn't do so)" (cf. past tense ～ばよかったのに。)

Example:

> 「君も来ればいいのに。」 "You should come, too."

---

As you may already know, 「～ばいいのに」 can also express the speaker's wish, usually counterfactual. E.g.

> 「上手に英語が話せればいいのに。」 "I wish I could speak English fluently."

---

For more usages of （～ば/たら いい）のに at the end of sentences, please refer to:

- [What does のに mean at the end of this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/42414/9831)
- [Expressing a regretful wish](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/35712/9831)

Answer (score 1):

> そんなに聞いてほしいなら言えばいいのに

"If you want me to understand, you better say it."
〜いいのに。 expressing the wishes.
のに also adds feeling of dissatisfaction, sadness or complaint.

For example:

> 「ごめん、明日仕事でデートに行けなくなった。」「楽しみにしていたのに。」
>
> 「今日ご飯外で食べてきた。」「え、電話してくれたらよかったのに。」
>
> 「あんなに勉強したのに、試験に落ちてしまった。」