# can't understand how で particle works with ～ばいいのに

Tags: meaning, particles, expressions, manga, particle-で

I am having trouble interpreting this sentence in a manga, the text was split in two bubbles which is why I separated them.
「日之出ん家でしてくればいいのに」　「そうすりゃもっと長く一緒に居られる」

from other threads, ～ばいいのに seems to imply wishing something happens or "should do (but haven't done)". which leads me to think it means something like: "I wish you would give me X, (it would be good) because Y"
"I wish you would give me hinode's address, (it would be good because) you would be able to stay together longer".

However, the で particle usually means "at" (at a place/home/...) or "with" (with a tool/with scissors/etc). I have no idea what it is doing here.

here is the screenshot in case it matters:
[image]

context: weird cat (seemingly evil/bad/....) on the right talking to the cat girl on the left

Comment: do https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/74577/how-to-use-%e3%81%b0%e3%81%84%e3%81%84%e3%81%ae%e3%81%ab and this https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42408/what-does-%e3%81%ae%e3%81%ab-mean-at-the-end-of-this-sentence answer your question?

Comment: @FelipeOliveira nope. these are the "other threads" I was talking about. They do cover how ～ばいいのに work, but they do not help me with understanding how the で particle is working here

Comment: I'm sorry to bother, but is this by any chance the original manga upon which the Netflix anime movie A Whisker Away was based?

Comment: @natiiix yes, it is called "泣きたい私は猫をかぶる" (nakitai watashi wa neko wo kaburu) in Japanese. The English release was called "A whisker away" instead of translating the original title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, this で is "at" (at a place). 日之出ん家で means "at Hinode's house". ～ばいいのに has the other meaning, which is a suggestion such as "why don't you ～". This する in the manga means "take a poop". So it means "Why don't you take a poop at (the bathroom of) Hinode's house?"

Comment: That does make sense, but how does her retaliation work in this case? I assume she means something like "No! I can't wipe my butt!" which she means she would be dirty and doesn't want him to see her that way? or am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: I have no idea because I don't know about the content of the manga. There would be some reasons why she can't wipe her butt at the bathroom of Hinode's house.

Comment: ohh I see. Thanks for answering :)